# Obter url da página seguinte com javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentanto comparar a página seguinte usando o history.go(), ou seja comparando a página seguinte com uma determinada url para obter um resultado positivo.

VEJA:

```
function a() {
    if (history.go(2) == "http://www.google.com.br") {
        alert("ok");
    }
}
</script>
<button onclick="a()">verificar</button>
```

Mas não acontece nada!

Uma outra coisa interessante seria se conseguisse exibir a url seguinte, com:

```
alert(history.go(2))
```

ou

```
alert(history.forward())
```

Mas o resultado que se obtem é indefinido.

Ou então verificar se uma URL está no history:

```
if (window.history.go("http://www.google.com.br")== true){
    alert("ok");
}
```

Ou até mesmo verificar se existe uma pagina seguinte no history, como:

```
if (history.forward() == true){
    alert("ok")
}
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Eu **suponho** que isso não é possível pois de certa forma compromete a privacidade do usuário.

Answer (score 2):

Os métodos `history.go`, `history.back` e `history.forward` não têm valor de retorno. O propósito destes métodos é navegar no histórico de páginas, e não saber qual é tal histórico.

Se fosse possível ler o histórico das páginas como você pretende, isso constituir-se-ia em uma falha de segurança, de forma que um código malicioso poderia aproveitar-se disso para saber quais são as páginas que o usuário acessou e então enviar essa informação para algum site malicioso, e portanto violando a privacidade do usuário.

Recomendo que você faça do lado do servidor o rastreio das páginas que o usuário acessou no seu site. Assim, você terá a parte do histórico relevante para o seu site e poderá redirecioná-lo conforme o necessário utilizando `history.go(url)`.